# Admin-on-rest, Edit Page - Incorrect Element Error

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm using admin-on-rest in my frontend side. But when I click Edit button in the list page, it orients to Edit page successfully but there is always an error like "INCORRECT ELEMENT". Do you know why?

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU3vZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr1dO.png)

App.js

```
import { DataTypeList } from './Components/DataType/DataTypeList';
import { FeatureList } from './Components/FeatureList';
import { DataPointTypeList } from './Components/DataPointTypeList';
import DashBoard from './Components/DashBoard';
import { DataTypeCreate } from './Components/DataType/DataTypeCreate';
import { DataTypeEdit } from './Components/DataType/DataTypeEdit';

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }

    // add your own headers here
    options.headers.set('X-Custom-Header', 'foobar');
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}
const restClient = jsonServerRestClient('http://localhost:3001/designer', httpClient);

const App = () => (
    // <Admin title="GAMMA" dashboard={DashBoard} restClient={jsonServerRestClient('https://arcane-citadel-28609.herokuapp.com/designer')}>
    <Admin title="GAMMA" dashboard={DashBoard} restClient={restClient}>
        <Resource name="datatypes" list={DataTypeList} create={DataTypeCreate} edit={DataTypeEdit} />
        <Resource name="features" list={FeatureList} />
        <Resource name="datapointtypes" list={DataPointTypeList} />
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

DataTypeEdit.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Create, Edit, SimpleForm, TextInput } from 'admin-on-rest';
import { DataTypeActions } from '../Actions/DataTypeActions';
import { DataTypeEditActions } from '../Actions/DataTypeEditActions';

export const DataTypeEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit title="Data Type - EDIT" actions={<DataTypeEditActions /> {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="id" label="Name"/>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

DataTypeEditActions.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { CardActions } from 'material-ui/Card';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import { DeleteButton, ListButton, RefreshButton, ShowButton, Edit } from 'admin-on-rest';

const cardActionStyle = {
    zIndex: 2,
    display: 'inline-block',
    float: 'right',
};

export const DataTypeEditActions = ({ basePath, data }) => (
    <CardActions style={cardActionStyle}>
        <ListButton basePath={basePath} />
        <DeleteButton basePath={basePath} record={data} />
        <RefreshButton />
    </CardActions>
)
```

Comment: Yes, because there's some error! Can you add details to your questions please? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added the sample code. The Edit page opens succesfully and I can see the detail of record but I didn't understand why I get this error.

My json data is like

[
{
"id": "1",
"name": "test",
"type": "test"
}
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your json data, try to return  { "id": "1", "name": "test", "type": "test" }, not a array.

Answer (score 4):

This error also appears if result's id doesn't match requested one.

Comment: Ya, I seen this, then I checked me logs and noticed the id weren't there at all.